# In go AuthFromMD is always expecting authorization as a header name. How can I override it.

Tags: go, authorization, grpc

I am using `github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/util/metautils` package for extracting the header, seeing [Link to AuthFromMD implementation](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/blob/master/auth/metadata.go#L24) I am sure that I can override AuthFromMD and have my own Header name instead of `authorization`. But turns out to be `var:=metautils.ExtractIncoming(ctx).Get(headerAuthorize)` this method call is always expecting the `headerAuthorize` to be `authorization`. Or it is throwing error. My use case is to have different HeaderNames so I can resolve multiple Headers using this method. Can some one please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is AuthFromMD is using `context.Context` in GRPC-Gateway. So Any request to grpc through the gateway is passing through this and the context is dropping any of the headers which is not in the METADATA defined in the context of this package.

Solution would be overriding this, and adding any of the custom headers to be not dropped from the Context

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that `AuthFromMD` expects the header to be named `authorization`. This is in part because it mimics the [HTTP header `authorization`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) which is always named the same.

I'm not sure that I understand your use case, but you can definitely reimplement `AuthFromMD` in your own package and modify it to take a header name.